# While loop working only once inside for each php

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach, while-loop

This is my Code. I know, the `while` loop will work only once. But `foreach` does not loop after fetching one value, i.e if I am selecting 3 checkboxes. Only one will pass the values.

```
if(!empty($_POST["list"]))  
      {  
$connect = @mysql_connect("localhost","***","***") or die (" this error");
mysql_select_db("edu_info")or die ("database does not exist"); 


          foreach($_POST["list"] as $list=> $val)  
           {  


$query=mysql_query("select * from students where id='$val' limit 1");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$user=$row['username'];
$number=$row['pphone'];
$name=$row['name'];
$pname=$row['pname'];
}
echo $user;
echo $number;
echo $name;
echo $pname;
    }
    }
```

This is my checkbox in html. The number of checkboxes is not fixed, it depends upon the query.Code below is just to get multiple checkboxes

```
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>
    }
```

Why is foreach not fetching values from all the selected checkboxes. Please help. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: dont run a query inside a loop like that, you only need one query which is far more efficenat

Comment: What is `$query1` and how it is linked with `$query`?

Comment: Am I right to guess that it only gets the last value you select? Because you overwrite the variables in your first snipped - and you don't really do anything with them (at least not from the code you've shown).

Comment: i am using $query_1 to get multiple checkboxes. i have used $id and fetched it $val via foreach. but the problem is when i used $val to get other variables like $user and when i echo them.. i get only one $username,$number,$name etc. Aren't i supposed to get multiple for each $val

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your while loop is overwriting the values each time.  I don't see where you're doing anything with the values you retrieve, hence, for example:

```
$user=$row['username'];
```

may be executing three times, but each time overwriting the previous value.  It's always giving you the last value chosen, right?  If so, that's because you're setting `$user` three times, and only after the last one are you doing anything with it.

Comment: after getting $val i am using it to select variables like $user from another database..but when i echo these variables i get only one value.. foreach is not executing for all the checkboxes i have selected .. so basically i'm getting one $val instead of many